# php - merge arrays keeping keys and incrementing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I've been trying to figure this one out all day but cant seem to explain, or get across what I'm trying to achieve. Lets say I have 2 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Dashboard
        )

)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => Toasts
        )

)
```

What I want to be able to do is merge the 2 arrays as follows:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Dashboard,
            [3] => Toasts
        )

)
```

But, if I have something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Dashboard
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Toasts
        )

)
```

I dont want to loose the value of the overriding element but increment it like so

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Dashboard,
            [3] => Toasts
        )

)
```

I have tried everything from array merge, recursive merge and even eval but I just can get my head around it. Has anyone come across this before? a function I haven't found?

Comment: How would it behave, if the two arrays have overlapping keys?

Comment: So, you want to know how many times a value appears in different arrays?

Comment: In same array, you cannot escape overwriting the same keyed values  cos of keys are uniq always.

Comment: @Dih the last section explains that the key would increment by 1 if the key exists.
@ EmCo no, im not sure what your saying there, sorry

Comment: it doesn't work and even if it did it would overwrite clashing keys/values

Comment: Will the arrays always have the same structure?

Comment: no, they could be larger, longer but always have one path, ie `$ar[1][2][3][4][5][6][7] = 'name';`

Comment: @LukeSnowden :  array merge, recursive will not work properly with numeric keys, if you can make your array associative it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$array['indexname'] = 'value';`. `array_merge()` or `array_push()` doesn't maintain the values having same/associative keys while merging, because there is no way to determine the next key.

Comment: The numerical keys are actually ordering positions. i.e. someone writes a plugin for something that im working on and sets the navigation position to '3.3.6', it will live in sixth position, of the third link in the third category.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a real answer but just a way to escape overwriting;

```
$a1 = array(array(2 => 'Dashboard'));
$a2 = array(array(3 => 'Toasts'));
$a3 = array(array(3 => 'Foo'));
$array = array();
foreach (array_merge($a1, $a2, $a3) as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $i => $value) {
        if (!isset($array[$i])) {
            $array[$i] = $value;
        } else {
            $array[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

```
Array
(
    [2] => Dashboard
    [3] => Toasts
    [4] => Foo
)
```

Comment: hi @qeremy, thanks to looking into this but this may fail on larger matrices. I didnt add that into the question because I asked this a while ago and no one could understand what I wanted to achieve.